# Binding Win10 MapControl while specifying MapAnimationKind

Tags: xaml, mvvm, bing-maps, windows-10

I'm using the `MapControl` for Windows 10 and binding it's `Center` property to my view model like so:

```
<Maps:MapControl x:Name="MapControl" Center="{Binding MapCenter, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

This works, but I'd like to use a parabolic animation when transitioning the map from one center position to the next when my view model changes. I'd like it to behave the way it would if I had called `TrySetViewAsync` from my code behind passing a `MapAnimationKind`:

```
MapControl.TrySetViewAsync(geopoint, 13, null, null, Maps.MapAnimationKind.Bow)
```

How can I achieve this effect while maintaining separation of concerns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of [MVVMLight Messenger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/JJ694937.aspx), we can trigger it from the ViewModel easily.

**About how to use MVVM Light in Windows 10 Universal App, see my answer in this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32186295/mvvm-light-cant-work-in-windows-10-universal-app/32186984#32186984).**

For example, the following method is placed in MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
private async void SetMapView(Geopoint point)  
{  
  await MainMap.TrySetViewAsync(point, 13,0,0,Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Maps.MapAnimationKind.Bow);  
}
```

Register the MainPage.xaml.cs to the default messenger provided by MVVMLight

```
Messenger.Default.Register<Geopoint>(this, Constants.SetMapViewToken, SetMapView);
```

Used a string Constants.SetMapViewToken as a token to identify the message and assigned SetMapView as an action

```
internal class Constants
{  
    public static string SetMapViewToken = "SetMapView";  
}
```

Trigger SetMapView method in ViewModel:

```
Messenger.Default.Send<Geopoint>(MyLocation.Coordinate.Point, Constants.SetMapViewToken);
```

**I've created a completed sample and uploaded to [Github](https://github.com/Myfreedom614/MapControlMVVMApp).**

Enjoy it:)

Comment: This is a viable solution. Thanks for the example. I actually ended up using a DataTriggerBehavior bound to my view model with a CallMethodAction that calls a method in my code-behind class. Similar effect though.