# MVVM light can't work in Windows 10 Universal app

Tags: mvvm, windows-10, win-universal-app, uwp

I tried to use **MVVMLight** in our Windows 10 Universal app, but it seems like that it totally can't work. I've seen this [blog](http://blog.galasoft.ch/posts/2015/03/using-mvvmlight-with-windows-10-universal-applications/)

> Nuget downloaded and added a reference to the MVVM Light assemblies
>
> Nuget also added the ViewModelLocator in the Application.Resources.

Can't see the Locator in `Application.Resources`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to create the ViewModelLocator manually, please follow these steps:

1. Create a new Windows 10 Universal app, for example: **MVVMLightUWPApp1**
2. Add reference to **MVVMLight** using **NuGet Package Manager**
3. Add a folder for your UWP app, for example: **ViewModel**
4. Under the ViewModel folder, add two classes: **MainViewModel** and **ViewModelLocator**
   [image]

In MainViewModel.cs:

```
namespace MVVMLightUWPApp1.ViewModel
{
    public class MainViewModel
    {
        public string MSG { get; set; }
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            MSG = "Test Message";
        }
    }
}
```

In ViewModelLocator.cs:

```
namespace MVVMLightUWPApp1.ViewModel
{
    public class ViewModelLocator
    {/// <summary>
     /// Initializes a new instance of the ViewModelLocator class.
     /// </summary>
        public ViewModelLocator()
        {
            ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);

            ////if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
            ////{
            ////    // Create design time view services and models
            ////    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DesignDataService>();
            ////}
            ////else
            ////{
            ////    // Create run time view services and models
            ////    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<IDataService, DataService>();
            ////}

            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
        }

        public MainViewModel Main
        {
            get
            {
                return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
            }
        }

        public static void Cleanup()
        {
            // TODO Clear the ViewModels
        }
    }
}
```

5. In App.xaml:

   ```
   <Application.Resources>
      <vm:ViewModelLocator xmlns:vm="using:MVVMLightUWPApp1.ViewModel"
                                  x:Key="Locator" />
   </Application.Resources>
   ```
6. In the View, set DataContext as below:

   ```
   DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
   ```
7. Now, you can set binding to VM, for example:

   ```
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding MSG}" FontSize="50" />
   ```

Enjoy it:)

Comment: Have a quick code question. thanks for this writeup, as it works, but how does the bind work? The Main isn't specified really and I'm not clear how the bind knows that Main's found under ViewModelLocator. Is it simply because it's public under MVVMLightUWPApp1.ViewModel?

Comment: @Poken1151 By Setting the Source={StaticResouce Locator} in the Binding, you are telling the binding to look for the resource with the key Locator (which we defined in Application.Resources in App.xaml file).  From there it looks for the Property Main in the locator